# About blending with Metal

Tags: swift, metal

In WebGL (OpenGL), write below

```
gl.blendFuncSeparate (gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE, gl.ONE);
```

In Swift Metal

```
descriptor.colorAttachments [0] .isBlendingEnabled = true
descriptor.colorAttachments [0] .rgbBlendOperation = .add
descriptor.colorAttachments [0] .alphaBlendOperation = .add

descriptor.colorAttachments [0] .sourceRGBBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
descriptor.colorAttachments [0] .sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
descriptor.colorAttachments [0] .destinationRGBBlendFactor = .one
descriptor.colorAttachments [0] .destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .one
```

Is it the correct answer?

P.S.
I asked the above question because I wanted to fix the WebGL code below to Metal. In WebGL, the blend is reflected in the whole, but in Metal, it is done in units of descriptors, so I think that it is necessary for both.

```
function setupRendering(){
    gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
    // alpha blending
    gl.blendFuncSeparate(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE, gl.ONE);
    // blackclear
    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, buffers.framebuffer);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  }

function renderMesh() {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, buffers[0].framebuffer);
    gl.useProgram(firstProgram);
    webgl.enableAttribute(planeVBO, attLocation, attStride);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, planeIBO);
    gl.uniform2fv(resolution, [width, height]);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, plane.index.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // 
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.useProgram(renderingProgram);
    webgl.enableAttribute(planeVBO, attLocation, attStride);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, planeIBO);

    //　
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, buffers[0].texture);
    gl.uniform1i(renderingUniLocation.textureUnit, 0);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, plane.index.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  }
```

Image of final output
[image]

Comment: I'll confess that I haven't thought too deeply about it yet, but presumably you've tried it.  Are you not getting the results you expect?

Comment: Since it is the correct answer on the WebGL side, I wanted to check it first.

Comment: Well on brief inspection, it looks right to me.

Comment: Thank you!
It turns out that there seems to be a problem in other parts.

Comment: Hopefully the problem isn't in a shader... those are so much fun to debug... not.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Certainly there seems to be no problem on the Shader side. It seems that the output is not good when offScreenRendering.

Comment: @ChipJarred the new selective debug shader function is amazing. Using it at the very moment ;)

Comment: @x001017 add an image of what you expect it to look like and the results you are getting.

Comment: For `sourceAlphaBlendFactor` try `.one`.

Comment: @Jeshua Lacock Thank you.In offScreenRendering, which I asked the other day, I want to render with alpha to a buffer and display that buffer using alpha.
I think that there is no big mistake because I replaced the one tested on WebGL with Metai, but since I am using Metal for the first time, I think that most of it is due to the mistake in usage.

Comment: Shader itself outputs a circular alpha with `float cA = smoothstep (0.5, 0.51, length (p)); return float4 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0 cA); `and RGB as black to the previously normalized p, and the final The one is to render the texture of the buffer as a circle with alpha as it is.
Is it better to have a sample program because it is difficult to understand?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock, thanks for the tip.  I haven't tried it yet, but you've piqued my curiosity.

Comment: I added
I asked the above question because I wanted to fix the additional WebGL code to Metal. In WebGL, the blend is reflected in the whole, but in Metal, it is done in units of descriptors, so I think that it is necessary for both.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock,　I have created a sample that includes the Jeshua Lacock Shader. I hope the final result output from textureFragmentShader will be the image as in the question.
I would be grateful if you could help me.

https://sgaworks.com/metalsample/MetalSample2.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the frame blending on the first drawable:

```
let defaultLibrary = mtlDevice.makeDefaultLibrary()
let vertexFunction = defaultLibrary?.makeFunction(name: "textureVertexShader")
let fragmentFunction = defaultLibrary?.makeFunction(name: "textureFragmentShader")
            
let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
pipelineDescriptor.label = "Drawable Render Pipeline"
pipelineDescriptor.sampleCount = mtkview.sampleCount
pipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexFunction
pipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunction
    
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = mtkview.colorPixelFormat
// alpha blending
//pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
//pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
//pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add
//
//pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
//pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
//pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .one
//pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .one
```

And I get the expected results:
[image]

UPDATE:

I also changed the color from Black to White for the drawable:

```
fragment float4 simpleFragmentShader(VertexOut vertexIn [[stage_in]],
                                 constant float2 &resolution [[buffer(0)]]) {

    float2 resolution0 = float2(resolution[0], resolution[1]);
    float2 p = (vertexIn.pos.xy) / min(resolution0.x, resolution0.y);

    float cA = smoothstep(0.5, 0.51, length(p));

    float3 colorB = float3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    return float4(colorB, cA);

}
```

Comment: it was very helpful! !! That's what I was looking for. With WebGL, it's the whole thing, but with Metal, it's quite difficult because only the final rendering side is good. Actually, when porting this webGL code, there is something I do not understand with the addition in the following part of renderToTextureRenderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor () which is also in this sample in Metal, I would like to ask the next question, but also power I would be very happy if you could lend me.